# Hashing Algorithm to use for short unique content ID

Tags: python, hash

I was wondering what would be the best hashing algorithm to use to create short + unique ids for list of content items.  Each content item is ascii file in the order of 100-500kb.

The requirements I have are:

- Must be as short as possible, I have very limited space to store the ids and would like to keep them to say  < 10 characters each (when represented as ascii)
- Must be unique, i.e. no collisions or at least a negligible chance of collisions
- I don't need to it be cryptographically secure
- I don't need it to be overly fast (each content item is pretty small)

I am trying to implement this in python so preferably a algorithm that has a python implementation.

Comment: Actually you explained regular counter.

Answer (score 0):

In leu of any other recommendation I've currently decided to use the following approach. I am taking blake2 hashing algorithm to create a cryptographically secure hex hash based on the file contents as to minimise the chance of collisions. I then use base64 encoding to map it to an ascii character set of which I just take the first 8 digits of.

Under the assumption that these digits will be perfectly randomised that gives 64^8 combinations that the hash can take. I predict the upper limit to the number of content items I'll ever have is 50k which gives me a probability of at least 1 collision of 0.00044% which I think is acceptably low enough for my use-case (can always up to 9 or 10 digits if needed in the future).

```
import hashlib
import base64

def get_hash(byte_content, size=8):
    hash_bytes = hashlib.blake2b(byte_content,digest_size=size * 3).digest()
    hash64 = base64.b64encode(hash_bytes).decode("utf-8")[:size]
    return hash64

# Example of use
get_hash(b"some random binary object")
```

Comment: In theory you could also improve the probability of no collisions by using base85 encoding instead of 64 however I am limited by what character sets the database will accept in the field name.